# altering html and saving html doc

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Been working on this for a while now, but maybe i am just searching the wrong thing to get the answers i need.

I have a dictionary whose keys are specific words i would like to find in a web page.  I would then like to highlight those words and save the resulting HTML into a local file.

EDIT: It occurred to me later that people my like to execute the code themselves.  This [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dwqdvbrg4f5stb5/AAD7uusC-vL3euDnnG_K0mYja?dl=0) includes the word dictionaries and the HTML of the page I am using to test my code as it should have the most matches of any of the pages i am scanning. Alternately you can use the actual [website](http://www.bbc.com/persian/institutional-37474133).  the link would replace rl[0] in the code.

```
    try:
        #rl[0] refers to a specific url being pulled from a list in another file.
        req = urllib.request.Request(rl[0],None,headers)
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        resp = opener.open(req)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(),'html.parser')
        resp.close
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        print("URL error when opening "+rl[0])
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        print("HTTP error when opening "+rl[0])
    except http.client.HTTPException as err:
        print(err, "HTTP exception error when opening "+rl[0])
    except socket.timeout:
        print("connection timedout accessing "+rl[0])
        soup = None
    else:
        for l in [wdict1,wdict2,wdict3,wdict4]: 
            for i in l:
                foundvocab = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(i))
                for term in foundvocab:
                    #c indicates the highlight color determined earlier in the script based on which dictionary the word came from.
                    #numb is a term i defined earlier to use as a reference to another document this script creates.
                    fixed = term.replace(i,'<mark background-color="'+c+'">'+i+'<sup>'+numb+'</sup></mark>') 
                    term.replace_with(fixed)
        print(soup, file=path/local.html)
```

the issue i am having is that when the soup prints it prints the entire paragraph for each word it finds and does not highlight. alternately i can say:

```
    foundvocab = soup.find_all(text=i)
```

and the resulting HTML file is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. the below code finds and replaces what i need.  now i just have display issues with the greater than and less than symbols which is a different problem.  thank you to those that spared the time to take a look.

```
    foundvocab = soup.findAll(text=re.compile('{0}'.format(i)), recursive=True)
    for fw in foundvocab:
        fixed_text = fw.replace('{0}'.format(i), '<mark background-color="'+c+'">'+i+'<sup>'+numb+'</sup></mark>')
        fw.replace_with(fixed_text)
```